# Find largest connected cells of value 1 or greater

Tags: javascript, algorithm, matrix

My goal is to find the largest connected "cell" of 1's in a matrix.

My approach has been to search the surrounding area of a cell that is not on a border and then if it hasn't been visited, and has a value of 1, increment the group.  I am absolutely sure that there are better, more recursive solutions out there, but I would greatly appreciate if someone would at least point me in the right direction.  I feel as though I'm getting closer.  Algorithms are still very new to me.

**Example test case**

```
[[0, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0]];
```

**Answer is 5 because there are 5 connected 1s of the largest group**

```
    <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
test = [[0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]];


// Answer should be 5

var Cell = function(x, y, val) {
    this.row = x;
    this.col = y;
    this.val = val;
    this.visited = false;
}

Cell.prototype.visit = function() {
    this.visited = true;
}

var CellMatrix = function(arr) {
    inst = [];
    for(i=0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
        for(k=0; k < arr.length; k++) {
            inst.push(new Cell(i, k, arr[i][k]));
        }
    }
    this.length = inst.length;
    //console.log(inst);
    return inst;
}

function find(row, col, cells) {
    for(i=0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        cell = cells[i];
        if((cell.row == row) && (cell.col == col) && (!cell.visited))
            return cell;
        else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function findLargestGrouping(cells, rows, cols) {
    console.log(cells);
    groups = []
    for(i=0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        cell = cells[i];
        // not a border cell
        if( (cell.row > 0) && (cell.row < (rows - 1))  )
        {
            if( (cell.col > 0) && (cell.col < (cols - 1)) ) {
                // console.log("cell at row " + cell.row + " col " + cell.col + " and val " + cell.val);
                groups.push(searchNeighbors(cell, cells));
            }
        }
        else { continue; }
    }
    return Math.max.apply(Math, groups);
}

function searchNeighbors(cell, matrix) {
    neighbors = [[cell.row - 1, cell.col - 1], // top left
                [cell.row - 1, cell.col], // top center
                [cell.row - 1, cell.col + 1], // top right
                [cell.row, cell.col - 1], // center left
                [cell.row, cell.col + 1], // center right
                [cell.row + 1, cell.col - 1], // bottom left
                [cell.row + 1, cell.col], // bottom center
                [cell.row + 1, cell.col + 1]];

    results = 0;
    for(i=0; i < neighbors.length; i++) {
        _row = neighbors[i][0];
        _col = neighbors[i][1];
        _cell = find(_row, _col, matrix);
        console.log("cell at row " + cell.row + " col " + cell.col + " and val " + cell.val);
        if(_cell) {
            if(!_cell.visited) {
                _cell.visit();
                results += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
}

window.onload = function() {
    matrix = new CellMatrix(test);
    results = findLargestGrouping(matrix, 4, 4);
    console.log(results);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should have a look at the A* (A-star) path finding algorithm, that (i guess) you could adapt to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *a lot* of global variables. Almost all of them, actually. I only see two `var` declarations, and those two are probably the ones that matter least (though all declarations matter - don't skip 'em).

You're lucky you're not calling functions with loops from inside other loops. Otherwise they'd both be using the same `i` variable, and things would get weird. Or rather, get broken.

So fix that first! Try running your code through [jshint](http://jshint.com), for instance, to get some basic refactoring/bug checking.

Secondly, while I applaud striving for object-oriented JS, it seems overwrought in this case.

If the task is indeed to find cells with a `1` in them, and all other cells have a `0`, then there's a shortcut to take. Since zero is false'y, and one is truth'y, they can pull double-duty as the `visited` flag: If a cell is zero, it's either been visited or is not worth visiting. In other words, we can ignore every cell that's false'y.

So if you just set cells to `0`, `false`, or `null` along the way, they'll be ignored later on. Same effect as your `visited`, but without the need for instantiating objects.

As for recursion, that's definitely an option here. Here's one such implementation:

```
function largestGroup(matrix) {
  var counts = [0];

  // count connected cells, starting with cell i,j
  function countConnected(i, j) {
    if(matrix[i][j]) {
      matrix[i][j] = null;
      return neighborsOf(i, j).reduce(function (sum, coord) {
        return sum + countConnected(coord[0], coord[1]); // recursion
      }, 1);
    }
    return 0;
  }

  // get neighbor coordinates of i,j
  // (ignores those that are false'y)
  function neighborsOf(i, j) {
    return [
      [i-1, j], [i+1, j],     // up and down
      [i, j-1], [i, j+1],     // left and right
      [i-1, j-1], [i-1, j+1], // diagonally up
      [i+1, j-1], [i+1, j+1]  // diagonally down
    ].filter(function (coord) {
      // keep only those coordinates that match cells that
      // a) exist, and
      // b) contain something thruthy
      return matrix[coord[0]] && matrix[coord[0]][coord[1]];
    });
  }

  // copy matrix to avoid modifying the original
  matrix = matrix.slice().map(function (row) {
    return row.slice();
  });

  // look for cells with something in 'em, and
  // start counting connected cells from there
  for(var i = 0 ; i < matrix.length ; i++) {
    for(var j = 0 ; j < matrix[i].length ; j++) {
      if(matrix[i][j]) {
        counts.push(countConnected(i, j));
      }
    }
  }

  return Math.max.apply(null, counts);
}
```

It starts by copying the matrix, since it's going to be modifying it, and we don't want to modify the input - other code may hold references to it.

After that, it starts looping through its copy, looking for the first truth'y cell. It then calls `countConnected` with that cell's coordinates, which, in turn, calls itself on each neighboring cell that's of interest (i.e. not zero). Any cell that's visited gets set to `null`, which, like zero, is false'y. Thus visited cells are ignored.

Each truthy cell that's visited by `countConnected` will add 1 to the count; any false'y cells will add zero. And since cells are set to `null` the first time they're counted, they won't be counted twice.

Comment: @willredington315 Glad you found it useful. But stick around and see if there aren't better answers coming your way. I'm sure there's a smarter way than what I propose. And don't forget to click the checkmark on whichever answer you think is best - it'll mark you question as answered

Comment: Two more quick questions:  1) How are there not any repitions when finding the neighborsOf a paritcular cell?  2)  What does the line "return matrix[coord[0]] && matrix[coord[0]][coord[1]]" mean?

Comment: @willredington315 1) There is still repetition. But it doesn't lead to recursion; the neighbor coordinates are found, but immediately ignored if the neighbor cell is zero. Which also involves your other question: That line evaluates to return either true or false. The first check is to see if a matrix row exists at `coord[0]` (it'll be undefined otherwise, which is false'y). The second is wether the row _and_ column exists. If it does, but contains zero, it'll be false'y. So in all it says "return true if a cell exists at this row/ column _and_ it isn't zero; otherwise return false"